# Problems with xsl:result-document and the creation of multiple files from a single source

Tags: xslt-2.0

I’m having issues attempting to get XSLT 2's result-document element to work properly. What I have in this case is an xml file with subscriber data in it and an xsl that is designed to transform it into a CSV.

I have a need in the solution to be able to specify several product codes and have the xsl transform the source document into multiple files one for each code in my selection.

Upon executing the following using the Saxon transform tool as follows:

C:\XSLTransformer\Transform.exe -xsl:"Example - Multifile Writer.xsl" -s:"Example.xml"

I get the files being created with names of Data Export Flatfile - P-PRPL.txt and Data Export Flatfile - P-YLW.txt. Both of the files contain the field headers, but neither file contains any actual data.

So, to reiterate the pdts: and csv: parts of the XSLT are being used correctly, as I’m able to render the files, but it seems that the supplied document is either being ignored, or the transform tool is having issues processing it in some way.

I know the XSLT in the file works, as I have a “manual” version of it that works without issue, but this one, where I hope to be able to automate some of the file production but giving it a bunch of codes to work on isn’t.

I suspect that the problem possibly lies with the transfer of the $code variable into the RenderRows template, but I can’t seem to put my finger on what exactly it is.

All help appreciated.

Thanks.

```
Example - Multifile Writer.xsl
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" exclude-result-prefixes="#all" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:csv="csv:csv" xmlns:pdts="pdts:pdts">

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output name="text" method="text" indent="no" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:variable name="columnDelimiter" as="xs:string" select="'&#x09;'"/>
<xsl:variable name="rowDelimiter" as="xs:string" select="'&#x0D;&#x0A;'"/>

<!-- Modify this list to generate output for whatever other product codes you’re interested in -->
<!-- The solution will generate a new file for each product code. -->
<pdts:products>
    <product Code="P-PURPLE" FileCode="P-PRPL"/>
    <product Code="P-YELLOW" FileCode="P-YLW"/>     
</pdts:products>

<!-- Output Columns -->
<csv:columns>
    <column>Unique Reference Number</column>
    <column>Contact (Donor)</column>
    <column>Firstname</column>
    <column>Surname</column>
    <column>Company Name</column>
    <column>Address 1</column>
    <column>Address 2</column>
    <column>City</column>
    <column>PostCode</column>
    <column>State</column>
    <column>Country</column>
    <column>Email</column>
    <column>Mob Number</column>
    <column>Tel Number</column>
    <column>Product Offer</column>
    <column>Start Date</column>
    <column>End Date</column>
</csv:columns>

<xsl:variable name="path" as="xs:string" select="'C:\Temp\'"/>

<xsl:template match="/"> <!-- Match the root -->
    <xsl:for-each select="document('')/*/pdts:products/*">
        <xsl:variable name="filename" select="concat('file:///',$path,'Data Export Flatfile - ',@FileCode,'.txt')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="code" select="@Code"/>
        <xsl:result-document href="{$filename}" format="text">
            <!-- Output the CSV headers -->
            <xsl:call-template name="RenderColumnHeadings"/>                
            <!-- Output the individual rows -->
            <xsl:call-template name="RenderRows">
                <xsl:with-param name="prmPackage" select="/Subscribers/Organisations//Subscription[@PackageCode = $code]"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="RenderColumnHeadings">
    <xsl:for-each select="document('')/*/csv:columns/*">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
            <xsl:value-of select="$columnDelimiter"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:value-of select="$rowDelimiter"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="RenderRows">
    <xsl:param name="prmPackage"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$prmPackage">

        <!-- Variables: Life made simpler -->
        <xsl:variable name="subscription" as="element(Subscription)" select="."/>
        <xsl:variable name="subscriber" as="element(BusinessUnit)" select="$subscription/../../."/>
        <xsl:variable name="organisation" as="element(Organisation)" select="$subscriber/../../."/>
        <xsl:variable name="memberAddress" as="element(Address)" select="$subscriber//Address[@Type='Subscription']/."/>

        <xsl:for-each select="$subscription//Recipient"><!-- Recipients -->
            <xsl:variable name="publication" as="element(Publication)" select="./../../."/>

            <xsl:value-of select="$subscription/@Id"/><!-- URN -->
            <xsl:value-of select="$columnDelimiter"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat($subscriber/Contact/@Forename,' ',$subscriber/Contact/@Surname)"/><!-- Contact (Donor) -->
            <xsl:value-of select="$columnDelimiter"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(@ContactDisplayName,' ')"/><!-- Firstname -->
            <xsl:value-of select="$columnDelimiter"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(@ContactDisplayName,' ')"/><!-- Surname -->
            <xsl:value-of select="$columnDelimiter"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$organisation/@Name"/><!-- Company Name -->

            <xsl:value-of select="$columnDelimiter"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="Address/Line1"/><!-- Address 1 -->
            <xsl:value-of select="$columnDelimiter"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="Address/Line2"/><!-- Address 2 -->
            <xsl:value-of select="$columnDelimiter"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="Address/City"/><!-- City -->
            <xsl:value-of select="$columnDelimiter"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="Address/PostCode"/><!-- PostCode -->
            <xsl:value-of select="$columnDelimiter"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="Address/State"/><!-- State -->
            <xsl:value-of select="$columnDelimiter"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="Address/Country"/><!-- Country -->

            <xsl:value-of select="$columnDelimiter"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="@EmailAddress"/><!-- Email -->
            <xsl:value-of select="$columnDelimiter"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="@Cellular"/><!-- Mob Number -->
            <xsl:value-of select="$columnDelimiter"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="@Phone"/><!-- Tel Number -->

            <xsl:value-of select="$columnDelimiter"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$subscription/@Name"/><!-- Product Offer -->
            <xsl:value-of select="$columnDelimiter"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$subscription/@WhenStarts"/><!-- Start Date -->
            <xsl:value-of select="$columnDelimiter"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$subscription/@WhenExpires"/><!-- End Date -->

            <xsl:value-of select="$rowDelimiter"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

```
Example Source Document
<Subscribers>
<Individuals>
    <Individual Id="16493" Name="Alpha Zulu">
        <Contact Id="16493" Forename="Alpha" Surname="Zulu" EmailAddress="alpha.zulu@alphabet.tld.dm" />
        <Subscriptions>
            <Subscription Id="181570" PackageCode="P-PURPLE" Name="Mike + Digital Edition" WhenCreated="2014-05-04T04:03:17.237" WhenStarts="2014-06-01T00:00:00" WhenExpires="2015-05-31T23:59:59.997" SubscriptionStatus="Current">
                <GenericProducts />
                <SecuredAccessProducts />
                <Publications>
                    <Publication Id="148042" PublicationID="46" ProductCode="M-PURPLE" VersionNumber="1" Name="Mike Paid 1 Year" IssueCount="0" Quantity="1" ProductClassId="4">
                        <Recipients>
                            <Recipient Id="153364" ContactId="16493" ContactTypeId="1" ContactDisplayName="Alpha Zulu" Copies="1" WhenCreated="2014-05-04T04:03:17.247" EmailAddress="gZulu@alphabet.tld.dm" >
                                <Address>
                                    <Line1>123 AAA ST</Line1>
                                    <Line2></Line2>
                                    <City>CCC</City>
                                    <State>SSS</State>
                                    <PostCode>9999</PostCode>
                                    <Country>Australia</Country>
                                </Address>
                            </Recipient>
                        </Recipients>
                    </Publication>
                    <Publication Id="148043" PublicationID="114" ProductCode="M-RED" VersionNumber="1" Name="Delta Complimentary" IssueCount="0" Quantity="1" ProductClassId="34">
                        <Recipients>
                            <Recipient Id="153365" ContactId="16493" ContactTypeId="1" ContactDisplayName="Alpha Zulu" Copies="1" WhenCreated="2014-05-04T04:03:17.267" EmailAddress="gZulu@alphabet.tld.dm" >
                                <Address>
                                    <Line1>123 AAA ST</Line1>
                                    <Line2></Line2>
                                    <City>CCC</City>
                                    <State>SSS</State>
                                    <PostCode>9999</PostCode>
                                    <Country>Australia</Country>
                                </Address>
                            </Recipient>
                        </Recipients>
                    </Publication>
                </Publications>
            </Subscription>
        </Subscriptions>
        <Addresses>
            <Address Type="Subscription">
                <Line1>123 AAA ST</Line1>
                <Line2></Line2>
                <City>CCC</City>
                <State>SSS</State>
                <PostCode>9999</PostCode>
                <Country>Australia</Country>
            </Address>
        </Addresses>
    </Individual>
    <Individual Id="23477" Name="Bravo Yankee">
        <Contact Id="23477" Forename="Bravo" Surname="Yankee" EmailAddress="bravo.yankee@alphabet.tld.dm" />
        <Subscriptions>
            <Subscription Id="186018" PackageCode="P-YELLOW" Name="Mike Essential Package 10" WhenCreated="2014-07-04T08:50:04.767" WhenStarts="2014-07-04T00:00:00" WhenExpires="2015-07-03T23:59:59.997" SubscriptionStatus="Current">
            <GenericProducts />
            <SecuredAccessProducts>
            <SecuredProduct Id="64886" SCAProductId="1" ProductCode="S-YELLOW" VersionNumber="1" MembershipTypeId="2" Name="Mike News.NET Standard 10" MaxMembers="10" LockedMemberCount="1" Quantity="1" ExternalName="Mike Standard 10" ProductClassId="1">
            <Members>
            <Member Id="16106772" Forename="Bravo" Surname="Yankee" EmailAddress="bravo.yankee@alphabet.tld.dm" />
            </Members>
            </SecuredProduct>
            </SecuredAccessProducts>
                <Publications>
                    <Publication Id="151954" PublicationID="46" ProductCode="M-PURPLE" VersionNumber="1" Name="Mike Paid 1 Year" IssueCount="12" Quantity="3" ExternalName="Monthly" ProductClassId="4">
                        <Recipients>
                            <Recipient Id="157514" ContactId="23477" ContactTypeId="1" ContactDisplayName="Bravo Yankee" Copies="1" WhenCreated="2014-07-04T08:50:05.493" EmailAddress="gYankee@alphabet.tld.dm" >
                                <Address>
                                    <Line1>123 AAA ST</Line1>
                                    <Line2></Line2>
                                    <City>CCC</City>
                                    <State>SSS</State>
                                    <PostCode>9999</PostCode>
                                    <Country>Australia</Country>
                                </Address>
                            </Recipient>
                            <Recipient Id="157515" ContactId="10226666" ContactTypeId="1" ContactDisplayName="Whiskey Zulu" Copies="2" WhenCreated="2014-07-04T08:50:05.787" EmailAddress="" >
                                <Address />
                            </Recipient>
                        </Recipients>
                    </Publication>
                </Publications>
            </Subscription>
        </Subscriptions>
        <Addresses>
            <Address Type="Subscription">
                <Line1>123 AAA ST</Line1>
                <Line2></Line2>
                <City>CCC</City>
                <State>SSS</State>
                <PostCode>9999</PostCode>
                <Country>Australia</Country>
            </Address>
        </Addresses>
    </Individual>
    <Individual Id="73120" Name="Alpha Hotel">
        <Contact Id="73120" Forename="Alpha" Surname="Hotel" EmailAddress="alpha.hotel@alphabet.tld.dm" />
        <Subscriptions>
            <Subscription Id="183293" PackageCode="P-PURPLE" Name="Mike + Digital Edition" WhenCreated="2014-06-03T04:03:40.483" WhenStarts="2014-07-01T00:00:00" WhenExpires="2015-06-30T23:59:59.997" SubscriptionStatus="Current">
                <GenericProducts />
                <SecuredAccessProducts />
                <Publications>
                    <Publication Id="149560" PublicationID="46" ProductCode="M-PURPLE" VersionNumber="1" Name="Mike Paid 1 Year" IssueCount="0" Quantity="1" ProductClassId="4">
                        <Recipients>
                            <Recipient Id="155023" ContactId="73120" ContactTypeId="1" ContactDisplayName="Alpha Hotel" Copies="1" WhenCreated="2014-06-03T04:03:40.503" EmailAddress="Alpha.harvey@alphabet.tld.dm" >
                                <Address>
                                <Line1>123 AAA ST</Line1>
                                <Line2></Line2>
                                <City>CCC</City>
                                <State>SSS</State>
                                <PostCode>9999</PostCode>
                                <Country>Australia</Country>
                                </Address>
                            </Recipient>
                        </Recipients>
                    </Publication>
                    <Publication Id="149561" PublicationID="114" ProductCode="M-RED" VersionNumber="1" Name="Delta Complimentary" IssueCount="0" Quantity="1" ProductClassId="34">
                        <Recipients>
                            <Recipient Id="155024" ContactId="73120" ContactTypeId="1" ContactDisplayName="Alpha Hotel" Copies="1" WhenCreated="2014-06-03T04:03:40.543" EmailAddress="Alpha.harvey@alphabet.tld.dm" >
                                <Address>
                                    <Line1>123 AAA ST</Line1>
                                    <Line2></Line2>
                                    <City>CCC</City>
                                    <State>SSS</State>
                                    <PostCode>9999</PostCode>
                                    <Country>Australia</Country>
                                </Address>
                            </Recipient>
                        </Recipients>
                    </Publication>
                </Publications>
            </Subscription>
        </Subscriptions>
        <Addresses>
            <Address Type="Subscription">
                <Line1>123 AAA ST</Line1>
                <Line2></Line2>
                <City>CCC</City>
                <State>SSS</State>
                <PostCode>9999</PostCode>
                <Country>Australia</Country>
            </Address>
        </Addresses>
    </Individual> 
</Individuals>
<Organisations>
    <Organisation Id="13" Name="Alpha Limited">
        <BusinessUnits>
            <BusinessUnit Id="560" Name="Bravo WA, Australia" Facsimile="">
                <Contact Id="1062276946" Forename="Kilo" Surname="Bravo" EmailAddress="kilo.bravo@alphabet.tld.dm" />
                <Agency />
                <Subscriptions>
                    <Subscription Id="168271" PackageCode="P-YELLOW" Name="Mike Essential Plus Package 25" WhenCreated="2014-01-24T04:03:02.103" WhenStarts="2014-02-21T00:00:00" WhenExpires="2015-02-20T23:59:59.997" SubscriptionStatus="Renewed">
                        <GenericProducts />
                    <SecuredAccessProducts>
                        <SecuredProduct Id="60181" SCAProductId="3" ProductCode="S-MNP1Y" VersionNumber="1" MembershipTypeId="3" Name="Mike News.NET Premium 25" MaxMembers="25" LockedMemberCount="1" Quantity="1" ExternalName="Mike Premium 25" ProductClassId="2">
                            <Members />
                        </SecuredProduct>
                    </SecuredAccessProducts>
                    <Publications>
                        <Publication Id="133606" PublicationID="46" ProductCode="M-PURPLE" VersionNumber="1" Name="Mike Paid 1 Year" IssueCount="0" Quantity="5" ProductClassId="4">
                            <Recipients>
                                <Recipient Id="138626" BusinessUnitId="560" ContactId="8342" ContactTypeId="2" ContactDisplayName="Indigo Charlie" Copies="1" WhenCreated="2014-01-24T04:03:02.410" EmailAddress="indigo.charlie@alphabet.tld.dm" >
                                    <Address>
                                        <Line1>123 AAA ST</Line1>
                                        <Line2></Line2>
                                        <City>CCC</City>
                                        <State>SSS</State>
                                        <PostCode>9999</PostCode>
                                        <Country>Australia</Country>
                                    </Address>
                                </Recipient>
                                <Recipient Id="138627" BusinessUnitId="4807005" ContactId="121315" ContactTypeId="2" ContactDisplayName="Mike Sierra" Copies="1" WhenCreated="2014-01-24T04:03:02.423" EmailAddress="mike.sierra@alphabet.tld.dm" >
                                    <Address>
                                        <Line1>123 AAA ST</Line1>
                                        <Line2></Line2>
                                        <City>CCC</City>
                                        <State>SSS</State>
                                        <PostCode>9999</PostCode>
                                        <Country>Australia</Country>
                                    </Address>
                                </Recipient>
                                <Recipient Id="138628" BusinessUnitId="3844766" ContactId="149273" ContactTypeId="2" ContactDisplayName="Papa Delta" Copies="1" WhenCreated="2014-01-24T04:03:02.437" EmailAddress="papa.delta@alphabet.tld.dm" >
                                    <Address>
                                        <Line1>123 AAA ST</Line1>
                                        <Line2></Line2>
                                        <City>CCC</City>
                                        <State>SSS</State>
                                        <PostCode>9999</PostCode>
                                        <Country>Australia</Country>
                                    </Address>
                                </Recipient>
                                <Recipient Id="138658" BusinessUnitId="4807007" ContactId="18761725" ContactTypeId="2" ContactDisplayName="Sierra Bravo" Copies="2" WhenCreated="2014-01-24T13:58:06.787" EmailAddress="sierra.bravo@alphabet.tld.dm" >
                                    <Address>
                                        <Line1>123 AAA ST</Line1>
                                        <Line2></Line2>
                                        <City>CCC</City>
                                        <State>SSS</State>
                                        <PostCode>9999</PostCode>
                                        <Country>Australia</Country>
                                    </Address>
                                </Recipient>
                            </Recipients>
                        </Publication>
                    </Publications>
                    </Subscription>
                    <Subscription Id="202338" PackageCode="P-YELLOW" Name="Mike Essential Plus Package 25" WhenCreated="2015-01-24T04:03:04.277" WhenStarts="2015-02-21T00:00:00" WhenExpires="2016-02-20T23:59:59.997" SubscriptionStatus="Current">
                    <GenericProducts />
                        <SecuredAccessProducts>
                            <SecuredProduct Id="71637" SCAProductId="3" ProductCode="S-MNP1Y" VersionNumber="1" MembershipTypeId="3" Name="Mike News.NET Premium 25" MaxMembers="25" LockedMemberCount="1" Quantity="1" ExternalName="Mike Premium 25" ProductClassId="2">
                                <Members>
                                    <Member Id="5351" Forename="Indigo" Surname="Charlie" EmailAddress="indigo.charlie@alphabet.tld.dm" />
                                    <Member Id="7755" Forename="Kilo" Surname="Bravo" EmailAddress="kilo.bravo@alphabet.tld.dm" />
                                    <Member Id="7756" Forename="Lima" Surname="Charlie" EmailAddress="lima.charlie@alphabet.tld.dm" />
                                    <Member Id="7758" Forename="Tango" Surname="Romeo" EmailAddress="tango.romeo@alphabet.tld.dm" />
                                    <Member Id="104333" Forename="Mike" Surname="Sierra" EmailAddress="mike.sierra@alphabet.tld.dm" />
                                    <Member Id="109664" Forename="Delta" Surname="Mike" EmailAddress="delta.mike@alphabet.tld.dm" />
                                    <Member Id="128216" Forename="Papa" Surname="Delta" EmailAddress="papa.delta@alphabet.tld.dm" />
                                    <Member Id="9599153" Forename="Sierra" Surname="Bravo" EmailAddress="sierra.bravo@alphabet.tld.dm" />
                                    <Member Id="9644184" Forename="Mike" Surname="Bravo" EmailAddress="mike.bravo@alphabet.tld.dm" />
                                    <Member Id="12953504" Forename="Sierra" Surname="Papa" EmailAddress="sierra.papa@alphabet.tld.dm" />
                                    <Member Id="12953505" Forename="Kilo" Surname="Mike" EmailAddress="kilo.mike@alphabet.tld.dm" />
                                    <Member Id="12953927" Forename="Alpha" Surname="Juliet" EmailAddress="alpha.juliet@alphabet.tld.dm" />
                                    <Member Id="16059657" Forename="Kilo" Surname="Delta" EmailAddress="kilo.delta@alphabet.tld.dm" />
                                    <Member Id="16061101" Forename="Bravo" Surname="Whiskey" EmailAddress="bravo.whiskey@alphabet.tld.dm" />
                                    <Member Id="16061102" Forename="November" Surname="Echo" EmailAddress="november.echo@alphabet.tld.dm" />
                                    <Member Id="16350124" Forename="Kilo" Surname="Papa" EmailAddress="kilo.papa@alphabet.tld.dm" />
                                    <Member Id="16350125" Forename="November" Surname="Charlie" EmailAddress="november.charlie@alphabet.tld.dm" />
                                    <Member Id="16372932" Forename="Hotel" Surname="Hotel" EmailAddress="hotel.hotel@alphabet.tld.dm" />
                                    <Member Id="16372933" Forename="Sierra" Surname="Juliet" EmailAddress="sierra.juliet@alphabet.tld.dm" />
                                    <Member Id="38777399" Forename="Sierra" Surname="Romeo" EmailAddress="sierra.romeo@alphabet.tld.dm" />
                                </Members>
                            </SecuredProduct>
                        </SecuredAccessProducts>
                        <Publications>
                            <Publication Id="166113" PublicationID="46" ProductCode="M-GREEN" VersionNumber="1" Name="Mike Paid 1 Year" IssueCount="0" Quantity="5" ProductClassId="4">
                                <Recipients>
                                    <Recipient Id="172383" BusinessUnitId="560" ContactId="8342" ContactTypeId="2" ContactDisplayName="Indigo Charlie" Copies="1" WhenCreated="2015-01-24T04:03:04.287" EmailAddress="ichalmers@alphabet.tld.dm" >
                                        <Address>
                                            <Line1>123 AAA ST</Line1>
                                            <Line2></Line2>
                                            <City>CCC</City>
                                            <State>SSS</State>
                                            <PostCode>9999</PostCode>
                                            <Country>Australia</Country>
                                        </Address>
                                    </Recipient>
                                    <Recipient Id="172384" BusinessUnitId="4807005" ContactId="121315" ContactTypeId="2" ContactDisplayName="Mike Sierra" Copies="1" WhenCreated="2015-01-24T04:03:04.290" EmailAddress="mike.sierra@alphabet.tld.dm" >
                                        <Address>
                                            <Line1>123 AAA ST</Line1>
                                            <Line2></Line2>
                                            <City>CCC</City>
                                            <State>SSS</State>
                                            <PostCode>9999</PostCode>
                                            <Country>Australia</Country>
                                        </Address>
                                    </Recipient>
                                    <Recipient Id="172385" BusinessUnitId="3844766" ContactId="149273" ContactTypeId="2" ContactDisplayName="Papa Delta" Copies="1" WhenCreated="2015-01-24T04:03:04.297" EmailAddress="papa.delta@alphabet.tld.dm" >
                                        <Address>
                                            <Line1>123 AAA ST</Line1>
                                            <Line2></Line2>
                                            <City>CCC</City>
                                            <State>SSS</State>
                                            <PostCode>9999</PostCode>
                                            <Country>Australia</Country>
                                        </Address>
                                    </Recipient>
                                    <Recipient Id="172386" BusinessUnitId="4807007" ContactId="18761725" ContactTypeId="2" ContactDisplayName="Sierra Bravo" Copies="2" WhenCreated="2015-01-24T04:03:04.303" EmailAddress="sierra.bravo@alphabet.tld.dm" >
                                        <Address>
                                            <Line1>123 AAA ST</Line1>
                                            <Line2></Line2>
                                            <City>CCC</City>
                                            <State>SSS</State>
                                            <PostCode>9999</PostCode>
                                            <Country>Australia</Country>
                                        </Address>
                                    </Recipient>
                                </Recipients>
                            </Publication>
                        </Publications>
                    </Subscription>
                </Subscriptions>
                <Addresses>
                    <Address Type="Subscription">
                        <Line1>123 AAA ST</Line1>
                        <Line2 />
                        <City>CCC</City>
                        <State>SSS</State>
                        <PostCode>9999</PostCode>
                        <Country>Australia</Country>
                    </Address>
                    <Address Type="Standard">
                        <Line1>123 AAA ST</Line1>
                        <Line2 />
                        <City>CCC</City>
                        <State>SSS</State>
                        <PostCode>9999</PostCode>
                        <Country>Australia</Country>
                    </Address>
                    <Address Type="Charlie Register">
                        <Line1>123 AAA ST</Line1>
                        <Line2 />
                        <City>CCC</City>
                        <State>SSS</State>
                        <PostCode>9999</PostCode>
                        <Country>Australia</Country>
                    </Address>
                </Addresses>
            </BusinessUnit>
        </BusinessUnits>
    </Organisation>
    <Organisation Id="17" Name="Bravo Limited">
        <BusinessUnits>
            <BusinessUnit Id="546" Name="Echo PERTH, WA, Australia" MSDynamicsId="35352" Facsimile="61 8 6218 8880">
                <Contact Id="1084704665" Forename="Hotel" Surname="Whiskey" EmailAddress="hotel.whiskey@alphabet.tld.dm" />
                <Agency />
                <Subscriptions>
                    <Subscription Id="176647" Name="Mike Paid 1 Year" WhenCreated="2014-04-14T10:14:43.287" WhenStarts="2014-06-21T00:00:00" WhenExpires="2015-06-20T23:59:59.997" SubscriptionStatus="Current">
                        <GenericProducts />
                        <SecuredAccessProducts />
                        <Publications>
                            <Publication Id="142935" PublicationID="46" ProductCode="M-GREEN" VersionNumber="1" Name="Mike Paid 1 Year" IssueCount="12" Quantity="10" ProductClassId="4">
                                <Recipients>
                                    <Recipient Id="148228" BusinessUnitId="546" ContactId="1062276276" ContactTypeId="2" ContactDisplayName="Romeo Charlie" Copies="6" WhenCreated="2014-04-14T11:51:17.710" EmailAddress="romeo.charlie@alphabet.tld.dm" >
                                        <Address>
                                            <Line1>123 AAA ST</Line1>
                                            <Line2></Line2>
                                            <City>CCC</City>
                                            <State>SSS</State>
                                            <PostCode>9999</PostCode>
                                            <Country>Australia</Country>
                                        </Address>
                                    </Recipient>
                                    <Recipient Id="175024" BusinessUnitId="4807112" ContactId="10226666" ContactTypeId="2" ContactDisplayName="Whiskey Zulu" Copies="4" WhenCreated="2015-02-19T14:22:01.540" EmailAddress="" >
                                        <Address />
                                    </Recipient>
                                </Recipients>
                            </Publication>
                        </Publications>
                    </Subscription>
                </Subscriptions>
                <Addresses>
                    <Address Type="Subscription">
                        <Line1>123 AAA ST</Line1>
                        <Line2 />
                        <City>CCC</City>
                        <State>SSS</State>
                        <PostCode>9999</PostCode>
                        <Country>Australia</Country>
                    </Address>
                    <Address Type="Standard">
                        <Line1>123 AAA ST</Line1>
                        <Line2 />
                        <City>CCC</City>
                        <State>SSS</State>
                        <PostCode>9999</PostCode>
                        <Country>Australia</Country>
                    </Address>
                    <Address Type="Charlie Register">
                        <Line1>123 AAA ST</Line1>
                        <Line2 />
                        <City>CCC</City>
                        <State>SSS</State>
                        <PostCode>9999</PostCode>
                        <Country>Australia</Country>
                    </Address>
                </Addresses>
            </BusinessUnit>
        </BusinessUnits>
    </Organisation>
    <Organisation Id="32" Name="Delta Limited">
        <BusinessUnits>
            <BusinessUnit Id="70579" Name="Mike VIC, Australia" Facsimile="">
                <Contact Id="17874450" Forename="Kilo" Surname="Foxtrot" EmailAddress="kilo.foxtrot@alphabet.tld.dm" />
                <Agency />
                <Subscriptions>
                    <Subscription Id="173024" PackageCode="P-YELLOW" Name="Mike Essential Plus Package 25" WhenCreated="2014-03-19T04:04:28.137" WhenStarts="2014-04-16T00:00:00" WhenExpires="2015-04-15T23:59:59.997" SubscriptionStatus="Current">
                        <GenericProducts />
                        <SecuredAccessProducts>
                            <SecuredProduct Id="61926" SCAProductId="3" ProductCode="S-MNP1Y" VersionNumber="1" MembershipTypeId="3" Name="Mike News.NET Premium 25" MaxMembers="25" LockedMemberCount="1" Quantity="1" ExternalName="Mike Premium 25" ProductClassId="2">
                                <Members>
                                    <Member Id="514" Forename="Romeo" Surname="Lima" EmailAddress="romeo.lima@alphabet.tld.dm" />
                                    <Member Id="104734" Forename="Romeo" Surname="Mike" EmailAddress="romeo.mike@alphabet.tld.dm" />
                                    <Member Id="1007933" Forename="Romeo" Surname="Bravo" EmailAddress="romeo.bravo@alphabet.tld.dm" />
                                    <Member Id="1087600" Forename="Delta" Surname="Foxtrot" EmailAddress="delta.foxtrot@alphabet.tld.dm" />
                                    <Member Id="2408219" Forename="Alpha" Surname="Lima" EmailAddress="alpha.lima@alphabet.tld.dm" />
                                    <Member Id="9597365" Forename="Kilo" Surname="Foxtrot" EmailAddress="kilo.foxtrot@alphabet.tld.dm" />
                                    <Member Id="9983336" Forename="Juliet" Surname="Delta" EmailAddress="juliet.delta@alphabet.tld.dm" />
                                    <Member Id="9983338" Forename="Alpha" Surname="Charlie" EmailAddress="alpha.charlie@alphabet.tld.dm" />
                                    <Member Id="12975663" Forename="Sierra" Surname="Juliet" EmailAddress="sierra.juliet@alphabet.tld.dm" />
                                    <Member Id="16349491" Forename="Alpha" Surname="Mike" EmailAddress="alpha.mike@alphabet.tld.dm" />
                                </Members>
                            </SecuredProduct>
                        </SecuredAccessProducts>
                        <Publications>
                            <Publication Id="137472" PublicationID="46" ProductCode="M-GREEN" VersionNumber="1" Name="Mike Paid 1 Year" IssueCount="0" Quantity="5" ProductClassId="4">
                            <Recipients>
                                <Recipient Id="142694" BusinessUnitId="70579" ContactId="23270" ContactTypeId="2" ContactDisplayName="Bravo Hotel" Copies="5" WhenCreated="2014-03-19T04:04:28.240" EmailAddress="" >
                                    <Address>
                                        <Line1>123 AAA ST</Line1>
                                        <Line2></Line2>
                                        <City>CCC</City>
                                        <State>SSS</State>
                                        <PostCode>9999</PostCode>
                                        <Country>Australia</Country>
                                    </Address>
                                </Recipient>
                            </Recipients>
                            </Publication>
                        </Publications>
                    </Subscription>
                </Subscriptions>
                <Addresses>
                    <Address Type="Subscription">
                        <Line1>123 AAA ST</Line1>
                        <Line2 />
                        <City>CCC</City>
                        <State>SSS</State>
                        <PostCode>9999</PostCode>
                        <Country>Australia</Country>
                    </Address>
                    <Address Type="Standard">
                        <Line1>123 AAA ST</Line1>
                        <Line2 />
                        <City>CCC</City>
                        <State>SSS</State>
                        <PostCode>9999</PostCode>
                        <Country>Australia</Country>
                    </Address>
                    <Address Type="Charlie Register">
                        <Line1>123 AAA ST</Line1>
                        <Line2 />
                        <City>CCC</City>
                        <State>SSS</State>
                        <PostCode>9999</PostCode>
                        <Country>Australia</Country>
                    </Address>
                </Addresses>
            </BusinessUnit>
        </BusinessUnits>
    </Organisation>     
</Organisations>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
<xsl:template match="/"> <!-- Match the root -->
    <xsl:for-each select="document('')/*/pdts:products/*">
        <xsl:variable name="filename" select="concat('file:///',$path,'Data Export Flatfile - ',@FileCode,'.txt')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="code" select="@Code"/>
        <xsl:result-document href="{$filename}" format="text">
            <!-- Output the CSV headers -->
            <xsl:call-template name="RenderColumnHeadings"/>                
            <!-- Output the individual rows -->
            <xsl:call-template name="RenderRows">
                <xsl:with-param name="prmPackage" select="/Subscribers/Organisations//Subscription[@PackageCode = $code]"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

to

```
<xsl:template match="/"> <!-- Match the root -->
    <xsl:variable name="root" select="."/>
    <xsl:for-each select="document('')/*/pdts:products/*">
        <xsl:variable name="filename" select="concat('file:///',$path,'Data Export Flatfile - ',@FileCode,'.txt')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="code" select="@Code"/>
        <xsl:result-document href="{$filename}" format="text">
            <!-- Output the CSV headers -->
            <xsl:call-template name="RenderColumnHeadings"/>                
            <!-- Output the individual rows -->
            <xsl:call-template name="RenderRows">
                <xsl:with-param name="prmPackage" select="$root/Subscribers/Organisations//Subscription[@PackageCode = $code]"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```